How to automate downloading data from webpage?
I am trying to automate the downloading of an Excel files from an open Government website using Python and Selenium. I've tried XPath to select and click on buttons, but the script doesn't select the button correctly. The manual process is select:

Ship Movements (top left of page)
Next 7 days (right of page)
Tools (right of page)
Export to Excel (right of page)

Any suggestions would be useful.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

xpath_ship_movements="//*[@id='Traffic']"
# xpath_ship_movements="xpath_full='/html/body/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a'"
xpath_days='//*[@id="rptGrid"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]'
xpath_tools='//*[@id="rptGrid"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[3]'
xpath_export='//*[@id="MSQ-WEB-0001"]'
url="https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/#"


driver = webdriver.Edge()

# Open the webpage
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Wait for and click the "Ship Movements" button
ship_movements_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_ship_movements)))
ship_movements_button.click()

# Wait for and click the "Next 7 days" button
next_7_days_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_days)))
next_7_days_button.click()

# Wait for and click the Tools button
tools_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_tools)))
tools_button.click()

# Wait for and click the Export to Excel option
export_to_excel = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_export)))
export_to_excel.click()

# Wait for the export to complete
time.sleep(10)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()


I think you will need to install WebDriver for browser in your local machine. For example if you're using MS Edge, download and install the WebDriver from Microsoft Edge WebDriver page.
After installation, try the modified code below (remember to replace with the path of installed driver):
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

def download_excel_file(url, xpath_ship_movements, xpath_days, xpath_tools, xpath_export):
    try:
        # Initialize the WebDriver (replace with the path of installed driver)
        driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='path/to/msedgedriver.exe')

        # Open the webpage
        driver.get(url)
        driver.maximize_window()

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

        # Wait for and click the "Ship Movements" button
        ship_movements_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_ship_movements)))
        ship_movements_button.click()

        # Wait for and click the "Next 7 days" button
        next_7_days_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_days)))
        next_7_days_button.click()

        # Wait for and click the Tools button
        tools_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_tools)))
        tools_button.click()

        # Wait for and click the Export to Excel option
        export_to_excel = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_export)))
        export_to_excel.click()

        # Wait for the export to complete (you can adjust the sleep time as needed)
        time.sleep(10)

        # Close the browser
        driver.quit()
        print("Excel file downloaded successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")

# Example usage
url = "https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/#"
xpath_ship_movements = "//*[@id='Traffic']"
xpath_days = '//*[@id="rptGrid"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]'
xpath_tools = '//*[@id="rptGrid"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[3]'
xpath_export = '//*[@id="MSQ-WEB-0001"]'

download_excel_file(url, xpath_ship_movements, xpath_days, xpath_tools, xpath_export)


Thanks, I set the driver path using service=Service(driver_path)         driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)), but the function fails on the line ship_movements_button.click()

'Message: element click intercepted: Element <a id="Traffic" data-id="Traffic-Ship Movements">...</a> is not clickable at point (158, 80)

Maybe it's taking longer than usual to load. Try using visibility_of_element_located (instead of element_to_be_clickable) in your wait conditions

Or increase the wait time from 20sec to 40sec.

still not working, does the code work on your PC?
